# JavaScript - How to list properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, methods, ecmascript-2016

Is there a way to list all properties of an object (which may be even a function) including non-enumerable ones, but without using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` or other methods of `Object`?

So, for example, I need to get all properties of native `String` constructor (`fromCharCode`, `fromCodePoint`, `raw`, etc), but I'm not allowed to use native function from `Object` called `getOwnPropertyNames`. Is there a way to achieve that?

I've tried `for..in` and `for..of` loops, but not all properties are listed. Also, I've tried `Object.keys`, but again, not all properties are listed. Also, to be make clear what I'm asking for: the following is not allowed:

```
var a = Object.getOwnPropertyNames.bind(Object);
console.log(a(String));
```

I'm asking this because I'm playing some game (called `ElevatorJS`) where a user writes a JavaScript program which should achieve something in restricted conditions. In this particular condition, the method `getOwnPropertyNames` is overriden and is equal `null`, so we are not allowed to use it. But, it turned out that they've hidden some non-enumerable property inside `String` constructor as a property, so I have to access it somehow. Also, they've overriden other methods of `Object` too (like `entries`, `getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, etc).

Is there a way to achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Reflect.ownKeys(String)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys), which will give you all the owned members of the argument.

Comment: So basically instead of using magic function A, use magic function B instead ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: Heh, yeah pretty much. :D